# detecting a windows path character in the end of a string

Tags: python, string

Being that windows uses a \ for path separation. and being that any letters after a \ are considered to be a escape character can you detect if a string has one at the end and add one if it does not.

My existing code is as follows. (it does not detect it).

```
def rename(folder, ext):
    folder = folder.replace('"', '')
    if folder.endswith('\\') == False:
        if folder.find('\\') == True:
            folder += '\\'
            print('windows')
    if folder.endswith('/') == False:
        if folder.find('/') == True:
            folder += '/'
            print('unix like')
```

Comment: The escaping only happens for string *literals* in your actual code.  If you're reading the `folder` value from somewhere else, no escaping will take place.  Can you give an example of data that your code "does not detect"?

Comment: After removing the " I get say C:\date as a string that is what I am working with

Comment: Please prefer `if condition:` to `if condition == True:` and  `if not condition:` to `if condition == False:`.

Comment: `str.find()` doesn't return a boolean, by the way. I think you want something more like `if '\\' in folder:`.

Comment: This makes no sense. Backslashes are path separators in Windows, not escape characters.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: Add a bit to the path, so I can rename the file without moving it. (I get a path, and add a extension to all the files)

Comment: You should probably be using `os.path`.

Comment: I am. I just need to fix the variable invited by the user

Answer (score -1):

You can check if a character appears at the end of a string with `str.endswith`. In this case:

```
yes = "C:\\path\\"
no = "C:\\path"

yes.endswith("\\")  # True
no.endswith("\\")   # False
```

That should let you detect, then to add:

```
if not no.endswith("\\"):
    no += "\\"
```

That's all there is to it.